# GlassFish4 error during artifact deployment

Tags: java, glassfish-4.1.1

During the transition from TomCat9 to GlassFish4 i ran into a problem. I tried to find the decision but could not.
When i was deploying the same app to TomCat it is all was ok.
Please help me.
Here is data from the glassfish log file:

```
[2016-10-13T12:26:59.641+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-LOGGING-00009] [javax.enterprise.logging] [tid: _ThreadID=15 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1476350818876] [timeMillis: 1476350819641] [levelValue: 800] [[
      Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (build 1)]]

    [2016-10-13T12:26:59.648+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-LOGGING-00010] [javax.enterprise.logging] [tid: _ThreadID=15 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1476350818876] [timeMillis: 1476350819648] [levelValue: 800] [[
      Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:00.043+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01115] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1476350818882] [timeMillis: 1476350820043] [levelValue: 800] [[
      Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:00.079+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01115] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1476350818882] [timeMillis: 1476350820079] [levelValue: 800] [[
      Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:00.087+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01115] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1476350818882] [timeMillis: 1476350820087] [levelValue: 800] [[
      Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:00.859+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [SEC-SVCS-00100] [javax.enterprise.security.services] [tid: _ThreadID=18 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1476350818917] [timeMillis: 1476350820859] [levelValue: 800] [[
      Authorization Service has successfully initialized.]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:00.952+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.glassfish.ha.store.spi.BackingStoreFactoryRegistry] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1476350818916] [timeMillis: 1476350820952] [levelValue: 800] [[
      Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:01.716+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [org.glassfish.grizzly.config.Utils] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1476350818882] [timeMillis: 1476350821716] [levelValue: 900] [[
      Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-1, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:01.873+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1476350818882] [timeMillis: 1476350821873] [levelValue: 800] [[
      Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 77ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:01.941+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [org.glassfish.grizzly.config.Utils] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1476350818882] [timeMillis: 1476350821941] [levelValue: 900] [[
      Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-2, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:01.954+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1476350818882] [timeMillis: 1476350821954] [levelValue: 800] [[
      Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 7ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:01.960+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [org.glassfish.grizzly.config.Utils] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1476350818882] [timeMillis: 1476350821960] [levelValue: 900] [[
      Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=admin-listener, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:01.972+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1476350818882] [timeMillis: 1476350821972] [levelValue: 800] [[
      Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 6ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:02.132+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=18 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1476350818917] [timeMillis: 1476350822132] [levelValue: 800] [[
      Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 3ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:02.134+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00017] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1476350822134] [levelValue: 800] [[
      GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (1) startup time : Felix (26,954ms), startup services(3,272ms), total(30,226ms)]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:03.263+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-JMX-00005] [javax.enterprise.system.jmx] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=Thread-12] [timeMillis: 1476350823263] [levelValue: 800] [[
      JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://DESKTOP-2DHDQFV:8686/jndi/rmi://DESKTOP-2DHDQFV:8686/jmxrmi]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:03.597+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [jts.startup_msg] [javax.enterprise.system.core.transaction.com.sun.jts.CosTransactions] [tid: _ThreadID=18 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1476350818917] [timeMillis: 1476350823597] [levelValue: 800] [[
      JTS5014: Recoverable JTS instance, serverId = [100]]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:03.809+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1476350823809] [levelValue: 800] [[
      HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.2.Final]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:06.563+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=15 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1476350818876] [timeMillis: 1476350826563] [levelValue: 800] [[
      Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 35ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:06.611+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-BOOTSTRAP-00027] [javax.enterprise.bootstrap] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1476350826611] [levelValue: 800] [[
      Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@141e879d as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@213860b8.]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:12.592+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=47 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1476350832592] [levelValue: 800] [[
      visiting unvisited references]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:15.863+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01002] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=47 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1476350835863] [levelValue: 800] [[
      Java security manager is disabled.]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:15.863+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01010] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=47 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1476350835863] [levelValue: 800] [[
      Entering Security Startup Service.]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:15.869+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01143] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=47 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1476350835869] [levelValue: 800] [[
      Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:16.003+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01011] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=47 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1476350836003] [levelValue: 800] [[
      Security Service(s) started successfully.]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:16.766+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00198] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=47 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1476350836766] [levelValue: 800] [[
      Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:16.778+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00198] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=47 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1476350836778] [levelValue: 800] [[
      Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:16.785+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00198] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=47 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1476350836785] [levelValue: 800] [[
      Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:16.846+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00200] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=47 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1476350836846] [levelValue: 800] [[
      Created virtual server server]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:16.851+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00200] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=47 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1476350836851] [levelValue: 800] [[
      Created virtual server __asadmin]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:17.417+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-CORE-00306] [javax.enterprise.web.core] [tid: _ThreadID=47 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1476350837417] [levelValue: 800] [[
      Setting JAAS app name glassfish-web]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:17.418+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00201] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=47 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1476350837418] [levelValue: 800] [[
      Virtual server server loaded default web module ]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:18.765+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.dol] [tid: _ThreadID=47 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1476350838765] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      enterprise.deployment.backend.invalidDescriptorFailure]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:18.767+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.dol] [tid: _ThreadID=47 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1476350838767] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      enterprise.deployment.backend.saxParserError]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:18.768+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=47 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1476350838768] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      Exception while deploying the app [main]]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:18.768+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00026] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=47 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1476350838768] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      Exception during lifecycle processing
    java.io.IOException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 129; Deployment descriptor file WEB-INF/web.xml in archive [main].  Attribute "xmlns:xsi" must be declared for element type "web-app".
        at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:211)
        at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:227)
        at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:96)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:881)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:821)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:377)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 129; Deployment descriptor file WEB-INF/web.xml in archive [main].  Attribute "xmlns:xsi" must be declared for element type "web-app".
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:324)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:245)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readStandardDeploymentDescriptor(Archivist.java:666)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:391)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:271)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:280)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:241)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:161)
        at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:203)
        ... 43 more
    Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 129; Attribute "xmlns:xsi" must be declared for element type "web-app".
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.addDTDDefaultAttrsAndValidate(XMLDTDValidator.java:1253)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1917)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:742)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:380)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:619)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3129)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:880)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:118)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:504)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:318)
        ... 51 more
    ]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:19.024+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=47 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1476350839024] [levelValue: 900] [[
      The web application [unknown] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.]]

    [2016-10-13T12:27:19.047+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=47 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1476350839047] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      Exception while deploying the app [main] : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 129; Deployment descriptor file WEB-INF/web.xml in archive [main].  Attribute "xmlns:xsi" must be declared for element type "web-app".
    org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 129; Deployment descriptor file WEB-INF/web.xml in archive [main].  Attribute "xmlns:xsi" must be declared for element type "web-app".
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:324)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:245)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readStandardDeploymentDescriptor(Archivist.java:666)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:391)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:271)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:280)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:241)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:161)
        at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:203)
        at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:227)
        at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:96)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:881)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:821)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:377)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 129; Attribute "xmlns:xsi" must be declared for element type "web-app".
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.addDTDDefaultAttrsAndValidate(XMLDTDValidator.java:1253)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1917)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:742)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:380)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:619)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3129)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:880)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:118)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:504)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:318)
        ... 51 more
    ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Glassfish is JEE container and tomcat not so you are missing xsi attribute in web.xml it should look like this

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
      version="3.0">
```

There are many versions of descriptors depending on version of JEE that you are using in your application

more examples here 
http://www.mkyong.com/web-development/the-web-xml-deployment-descriptor-examples/

Comment: My web.xml is already contains the same attribute. So, the problem is not here.

Answer (score 0):

Thx Slawomir for the right direction.
I found two ways to solve this problem:
1. Remove lines in my web.xml:

```
`<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >`
```

2. Remove all attributes from "web-app" tag (including "xmls:..." and so on).

But i am not understand why it is so?